# number_format() fails to convert scientific notation

Tags: php, syntax, logic

I have some float values being looped through an array that are outputting in  scientific notation.

I need to convert the scientific notation to a regular flat float long notation value.

I tried number_format(), but it still outputs in scientific notation until the very last cycle of my loop?

```
<?php
$parray = array(array('BTC-EXP','1',0.000097,1),array('BTC-VOX',7,number_format(0.000075,8),7));
for ($x = 0; $x <= 1; $x++) {
        var_dump($parray);
        foreach($parray as $pairp){
                echo "\nDebug info! Limit\n";
                echo $pairp[2];
                echo "\n";
                print_r(number_format($pairp[2],8));

        }
}

?>
```

output:

```
Debug info! midpoint
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "BTC-EXP"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [2]=>
    float(9.7E-5)
    [3]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "BTC-VOX"
    [1]=>
    int(7)
    [2]=>
    string(10) "0.00007500"
    [3]=>
    int(7)
  }
}

Debug info! Limit
9.7E-5
0.00009700
Debug info! Limit
0.00007500
0.00007500
Debug info! midpoint
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "BTC-EXP"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [2]=>
    float(9.7E-5)
    [3]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "BTC-VOX"
    [1]=>
    int(7)
    [2]=>
    string(10) "0.00007500"
    [3]=>
    int(7)
  }
}

Debug info! Limit
9.7E-5
0.00009700
Debug info! Limit
0.00007500
0.00007500
```

How do I convert my float values to long notation through an entire cycle (deny short notation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your $parray, you are storing one number as a float (0.000097) and in the other you're storing the result of number_format(0.000075,8), which is a string.

It's not surprising then, that when you call
`echo $pairp[2];` on 0.000097, that you see 9.7E-5, but when you echo it for number_format(0.000075,8) you see a string representation (0.00007500).

Let's do the same for `print_r(number_format($pairp[2],8));`.  When it's called for float (0.000097), it formats it as a string and you see 0.00009700.  When it's called for "0.00007500", this string is converted to a float 0.000075, which is then converted back to a string "0.00007500".